# how to play custom notification sound in ios push notification using FCM

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I'm using FCM to send push notification to iOS devices from the server but I'm getting the notification successfully but unable to play custom notification sound.

here is my payload

```
{
    "to":"myToken",
    "notification":{
        "title":"new message",
        "body":"Hello World!",
        "sound":"tweet_sent.caf",
        "badge": 3
    }
}
```

**Note:** Also i added 'tweet_sent.caf' file to Xcode bundle

Comment: Please replace "notification" key with “aps” key.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70939615/2126077 check my answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your answers and comments

It is working fine now after adding notification file in build phases (Xcode).

For Ref: [Playing a custom sound on receiving a remote push notification on iOS 12 from FCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55634620/playing-a-custom-sound-on-receiving-a-remote-push-notification-on-ios-12-from-fc)

Answer (score 0):

**Please replace `notification` key with `aps` like:**

```
{
    "to":"myToken",
    "aps":{
        "title":"new message",
        "body":"Hello World!",
        "sound":"tweet_sent.caf",
        "badge": 3
    }
}
```

And also add sound **`tweet_sent.caf`** file into your project resource location.

Comment: For FCM you use `"notification"` and not "`aps"`  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications

Comment: As per this link- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive , "aps" is part of Payload.

Comment: Firebase repackages the payload that is sent to it before it goes out. It recreates it in the way that is required for Apple. Your link shows how it is delivered to the app, not how you send it to firebase.

Comment: How do I add the sound to my `project resource location`?