How to change sound of push notifications of an iOS app programmatically?
I working on an iOS app for which I am required to change sound for push notifications. I am using Firebase Console to send notifications.
I put notification sound file in project and send its name in custom data through Firebase messaging in sound key. I found this solution after hours of searching but this solution doesn't seem to work. Is it even possible in iOS? If so how?

This question is similar to: How to send Push Notifications with custom sounds via the Firebase FCM Console. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There are other similar questions on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58973180/how-to-play-custom-notification-sound-in-ios-push-notification-using-fcm, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39335363/fcm-notification-in-ios-doesnt-play-sound-when-received, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811615/firebase-push-notifications-custom-sound

All you need to do are:

Make sure you've added the sound file to your project. Double check it in Project -> Build Phases. Supported types are aiff, wav, or caf as mentioned in this documentation UNNotificationSound.



The push notification payload must have a sound field that matches with the file name from the previous step. In this case is "sound": "pushSound.wav". I've created a mockup in Push Notification Console. The payload should be something like:

{
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "title": "Who's that?"
            "body": "Ringgggg....."
        }
        "sound": "pushSound.wav" //<- here
    }
}

It's supposed to work as usual if the project didn't include any Notification Extension.

This doesn't work if you are sending notifications using Messaging from Firebase console.

What is the payload that you received from FCM?
